# Electrophoretic Displays

Tags: lcd, display, optoelectronics

I am extremely interested in learning about [electrophoretic displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_paper). On their architecture, how they function and also would like to assemble one from the scratch for myself and see how it works (I have a bit of a chemistry background as well). So as you could see I am seriously in to this.

But so far I could not get hold of any good way of doing this after searching the web for some time.

I have a computer science background and my knowledge in electronics is very shallow. Would somebody be able to provide me some guidance on this? (Good online references, books etc. are welcome to be listed). If you think some college course would help, do let me know what type of courses I should be interested in following too.

Answer (score 1):

This paper from [Cornell](http://people.ccmr.cornell.edu/~cober/mse542/page2/files/Herz%20Electrophoretics.pdf) explains how they have a substrate, charged partics and an electrode covered over by glass.

You won't be able to make one yourself. That requires specialized equipment.

Comment: I think, if you have access to some decent university facilities, you could pull off at least a single-cell (e.g. 1 big pixel) electrophoretic panel. You'd need vacuum deposition equipment to get the indium-tin oxide onto the the glass, but after that, I think it would just take something to support the panels, and seal the liquid inside. Of course, if you want to have a multi-pixel display, you would need photolithography tools.

Comment: @FakeName: "You'd need vacuum deposition equipment". Am I the only one here who doesn't have that? :-/

Comment: @FedericoRusso - Apparently? I certainly have an old Welch vacuum pump in storage. I'd need a diff pimp, or a turbo pump (better, lower maintenance, and it doesn't need dry ice or LN2).  After that, it's just plumbing (well, and a 50A power supply).

Comment: @FakeName & FedericoRusso, thank you very much for the information. That really helps.

Comment: @FakeName, by the way do you know whether the same thing could be done with QRLPD, and whether it is available commercially?